# Why does deployed logic app through visual studio does not carry the custom created azure app service to new subscription

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-deployment

I have created an Azure logic app using Visual Studio Tools For Azure. I am able to deploy it perfectly on the same subscription. 
This Logic app consists of an azure app service(web api)
I need to deploy the same logic app to another subscription which does not have the azure app service deployed.
The logic app is deployed to new azure subscription but azure app service is not created. I believe that it is still pointing to previous subscription.
Please let me know how can I make sure that the web api is also deployed to new account and logic app points to app service in new account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the dependency，in your case，the logic app consumes the azure app service(web api). so you should first get azure app service(web api) created，then get your logic app created.

Or you could use the old azure app service(web api), but your need to update the app service(web api) reference in your logic app. that is to say, updating the subscription Id and resource group name to old subscription.

you can find more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid